# Scaling up case_when (tidyverse) for large dataframe with n rows

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, iteration, case

I have a dataframe "factDf" where I would like to fill in values in the column "trial_number" based on two conditions. I as well have a reference dataframe "dimDf", the columns of this reference dataframe serve as comparison values for the conditions and as well provide the values to be filled into the column "trial_number" of my target dataframe.

With the help of other users, I managed to find an approach that works for a simplified example. In the original reference dataframe, I have many more rows than in my the example dataframes (> 300). This is why I was wondering how I could "automate" this procedure so that the function iterates through all n rows of the original dataframe and I do not have to repeat the conditions more than 300 times.

**This is the simplified example**

*Original dataframe:*

```
    library(tidyverse)

    df <- data.frame(referenceColumn = seq(from =1, to = 10, by =1), 
                 a = c(10, 22, 30, 45, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                 b = c(20, 24, 40, 55, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                 trialNumber = rep(NA, 10), 
                 startTime = c(12, 22, 23, 31, 35, 36, 37, 46, 47, 50), 
                 endTime = c(18, 23, 24, 32, 36, 37, 39, 51, 53, 54))

    referenceColumn  a  b trialNumber startTime endTime
    1                1 10 20          NA        12      18
    2                2 22 24          NA        22      23
    3                3 30 40          NA        23      24
    4                4 45 55          NA        31      32
    5                5 NA NA          NA        35      36
    6                6 NA NA          NA        36      37
    7                7 NA NA          NA        37      39
    8                8 NA NA          NA        46      51
    9                9 NA NA          NA        47      53
    10              10 NA NA          NA        50      54
```

*Separation of reference and target dataframe:*

```
    dimDf <- df %>% 
      select(referenceColumn:b)

    referenceColumn  a  b
    1                1 10 20
    2                2 22 24
    3                3 30 40
    4                4 45 55
    5                5 NA NA
    6                6 NA NA
    7                7 NA NA
    8                8 NA NA
    9                9 NA NA
    10              10 NA NA
              

    factDf <- df %>% 
      select(trialNumber:endTime)

    trialNumber startTime endTime
    1           NA        12      18
    2           NA        22      23
    3           NA        23      24
    4           NA        31      32
    5           NA        35      36
    6           NA        36      37
    7           NA        37      39
    8           NA        46      51
    9           NA        47      53
    10          NA        50      54
```

*Case when that solves the problem in a simplified way (without automation):*

```
    dfNew <- factDf %>% 
      mutate(trialNumber = case_when(
        startTime >= dimDf$a[1] & endTime <= dimDf$b[1] ~ dimDf$referenceColumn[1], 
        startTime >= dimDf$a[2] & endTime <= dimDf$b[2] ~ dimDf$referenceColumn[2], 
        startTime >= dimDf$a[3] & endTime <= dimDf$b[3] ~ dimDf$referenceColumn[3], 
        startTime >= dimDf$a[4] & endTime <= dimDf$b[4] ~ dimDf$referenceColumn[4],
        TRUE ~ NA_real_
      ))

     trialNumber startTime endTime
    1            1        12      18
    2            2        22      23
    3            2        23      24
    4            3        31      32
    5            3        35      36
    6            3        36      37
    7            3        37      39
    8            4        46      51
    9            4        47      53
    10           4        50      54
```

In my original data, the reference dataframe has more than 300 rows / values to be filled into the target dataframe. I would be helpful for any recommendation about how I could scale this up. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good use case for a "non-equi join," specifically an overlap join or a rolling join. Much simpler to write and read, and much faster to run. These are supported since `dplyr 1.1.0`, and have been available in `data.table` and `sqldf` long before that.

```
library(dplyr)
factDf %>%
  left_join(dimDf, join_by(closest(startTime >= a), endTime <= b)) %>%
  select(trialNumber = referenceColumn, startTime, endTime)
```

Here's the result. If your ranges don't overlap, it might be  redundant to have both `closest()` (which picks the largest `a` that is equal to or smaller than `startTime`) and the 2nd test for `endTime <= b`, but I don't think it hurts.

```
   trialNumber startTime endTime
1            1        12      18
2            2        22      23
3            2        23      24
4            3        31      32
5            3        35      36
6            3        36      37
7            3        37      39
8            4        46      51
9            4        47      53
10           4        50      54
```